# Java compare two elements of objects in a list

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8, java-stream

I am converting one Object in list to another object looping through them with streams.

```
    response.stream().map(res -> new Req(res.getId(), 
res.getStartDate(), res.getEndDate())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Response object has  startdate and enddate for all it's objects and I am setting them to Req object. Now the records in the res objects may have gaps between startdate and enddate and I want fill those gaps with enddate  of last record and startdate of next/current record.

Ex:

```
startdate    enddate
 ---------   ---------
 01-01-2018  01-05-2018
 01-05-2018  01-09-2018
 01-12-2018  01-14-2018
 01-20-2018  01-25-2018
```

Then my Req object should have records as follows

```
startdate    enddate
 ---------   ---------
 01-01-2018  01-05-2018
 01-05-2018  01-09-2018
 01-09-2018  01-12-2018
 01-12-2018  01-14-2018
 01-14-2018  01-20-2018
 01-20-2018  01-25-2018
```

I want add a if condition in the stream and check the current and next objects of list and add the extra objects in request. Not sure if this can be achieved this way or I have to use two for loops.

Comment: Separate the data cleaning from the mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not that easy with streams. First you need to sort your responses by `startDate`:

```
List<Response> sorted = responses.stream()
         .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Response::getStartDate))
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Than create a method that will transform from `Response` to `Request`:

```
private static Request fromResponse(Response response) {
    return new Request(response.getStartDate(), response.getEndDate(), response.getId());
}
```

Finally the stream operation:

```
List<Request> req = IntStream.range(0, sorted.size())
                                 .boxed()
                                 .flatMap(x -> {
                                     if (x == responses.size() - 1) {
                                         return Stream.of(fromResponse(responses.get(x)));
                                     }
                                     Response left = responses.get(x);
                                     Response right = responses.get(x + 1);

                                     if (!left.getEndDate().equals(right.getStartDate())) {
                                         Response oneMore = new Response(
                                             left.getEndDate(),
                                             right.getStartDate(),
                                             left.getId());
                                         return Stream.of(fromResponse(left), fromResponse(oneMore));
                                     } else {
                                         return Stream.of(fromResponse(left));
                                     }
                                 })
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```